# How to inflate a single row in fragment which in under viewpager2 inside an activity?

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

In my viewpager2 , their are 2 fragments FragmentOne and FragmentTwo... I want to inflate Fragment one and Two . Currently what we do in normal fragment is not working in viewpager2 fragment. I want to showing vertical scrolling data in the fragments.
I am not able to inflate the one single row in the fragment. Please let me know what i am doing wrong.
I WANT THE FRAGMENT LIKE THIS...[image: FRAGMENTTWO]

```
This is the XML of Viewpager2, tabslayout...(This layout is Inside a activity)



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/Fragentstype2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabsvpg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/onerowshape"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/fbutton_color_orange"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/onerowshape"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/fbutton_color_orange"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomText"
            />


        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/tabsvpg"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabsvpg" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is Activity class---

```
        tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.tabsvpg);
        pager2=findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        frgrankAdapter=new PgrFrgrankAdapter(fm, getLifecycle());
        pager2.setAdapter(frgrankAdapter);

        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Prize Dist"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Rank"));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        pager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            /*    super.onPageSelected(position);*/
                tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
            }
        });

        pager2.setOrientation(ViewPager2.ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
```

This is FragmentsTwo for the viewpager...

```
public class VpgFgtwo extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView rcvfrag2;
    
    private ArrayList<RankModelClass> rankarraylist;
    private FG2Pgr2adapter fg2Pgr2adapter;
    FragmentVpgFgtwoBinding fragmentVpgFgtwoBinding;

    public VpgFgtwo() {

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        fragmentVpgFgtwoBinding= FragmentVpgFgtwoBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);

        //View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_vpg_fgtwo, container, false);
        rcvfrag2=fragmentVpgFgtwoBinding.recyclerViewfrg2rank;

        rankarraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        rcvfrag2.setHasFixedSize(false);
        rcvfrag2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        // adding our array list to our recycler view adapter class.
        fg2Pgr2adapter = new FG2Pgr2adapter(rankarraylist, this);

        // setting adapter to our recycler view.
        rcvfrag2.setAdapter(fg2Pgr2adapter);


        return fragmentVpgFgtwoBinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

this is xml for FragmentTwo

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgMainPg3dark"
    tools:context=".VpgFgtwo">





    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewfrg2rank"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayo
```

This is Fragment adapter for the view pager...

```
package com.example.pocketrocket;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class VPgrFragAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    public VPgrFragAdapter(@NonNull @NotNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull @NotNull Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
    }

    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int pos) {
        switch (pos) {
            case 0: {
                return new VpgFgone();
            }
            case 1: {

                return new VpgFgtwo();
            }

            default:
                return new VpgFgone();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

This is the Modal class which i am using to populate fragment Two.

```
public class RankModelClass {
    long rankposition;
    double prizewin;

    public RankModelClass( long rankposition, double prizewin) {

        this.rankposition = rankposition;
        this.prizewin = prizewin;
    }

    public RankModelClass() {
    }



    public long getRankposition() {
        return rankposition;
    }

    public void setRankposition(long rankposition) {
        this.rankposition = rankposition;
    }

    public double getPrizewin() {
        return prizewin;
    }

    public void setPrizewin(double prizewin) {
        this.prizewin = prizewin;
    }
}
```

This is the adapter for fragment B add data from modal class

```
public class FG2Pgr2adapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FG2Pgr2adapter.Hold> {
    private ArrayList<RankModelClass> rankarraylist;
    private final VpgFgtwo context;

    public FG2Pgr2adapter(ArrayList<RankModelClass> rankarraylist, VpgFgtwo context) {
        this.rankarraylist = rankarraylist;
        this.context=context;
    }


    @NonNull
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public FG2Pgr2adapter.Hold onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Hold(LayoutInflater.from(context.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.onerowforrankdes, parent, false));
        //return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull FG2Pgr2adapter.Hold holder, int position) {
        RankModelClass rankModelClass = rankarraylist.get(position);
        //Log.d("sizeuserdet", String.valueOf((rankarraylist.size())));


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

     class Hold extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        long position;
        double prizemoney;


        public Hold(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the single row...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/backgMainPg3dark"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/recentonerow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"

        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/backgMainPgbelow"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prizemoney"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gilroyextrabold"
                android:text="RECENT TRANSACTIONS"
                android:textColor="@color/fbutton_color_clouds"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/position"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/gilroyextrabold"
                android:text="#1"
                android:textColor="@color/fbutton_color_clouds"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>




</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Probably not all of that code is needed/ helpful when answering the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @thinkgruen can you give the answer...?.

Comment: sorry, I only encountered the question in the review queue, so I can only give advice how to improve the question.